# Identifying which value of a multi-row inserts fails foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

I have a multi-row insert that looks something like:

```
insert into table VALUES
(1, 2, 3),
(4, 5, 6),
(7, 8, 9);
```

Assume the first attribute (1, 4, 7) is a foreign key to another table and assume that this referenced table does not have the value '4'.  A MySQLExeption is thrown with error code 1452.

EXCEPTION: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbName/tableName`, CONSTRAINT `id` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `referencedTable` (`customer_id`))

Is there a way to identify which value caused the error?  I would love to give my user an error message that said something like:

```
Error: '4' does not exist in the referenced table.
```

I am using the .NET mysql connector to execute the insert.

Thanks-

Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be to query the referenced table first.

```
select id from referencedTable where id not in (1, 4, 7)
```

It seems that there should be a cleaner way...